# How to resize docker volume after creation?

Tags: docker

I would like to limit my docker volumes in size, So I don't have one container crashing my entire environment because of excessive writes depleting my storage space.

I found it is possible to limit volumes size at creation time using `--opt o=size=100m`
However Is it possible to change the size limit after I have created the volume?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about editing the volume opt parameters using the docker CLI/API: no.

If you're talking about resizing on the fly: it depends on the driver. TMPFS can be [expanded when remounted](/var/lib/docker/volumes/teste/_data), as well as [BTRFS](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-resize-expand-a-btrfs-volume-filesystem/), ZFS, etc, but that's not using docker CLI or API.

Comment: is there a method to do so manually? (not by docker CLI\API)?

Comment: What’s the type you used in the volume configuration? Do you have the command you ran to create it?